# Restricting users to not put URL and profound words in EditText

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm developing a forum app for my university, now, I want to restrict users to not put links/URL and profound words when posting a discussion on the app.

I have a simple validation on my EditText that says something like "Please refrain yourself from posting profound words / URL" if the text contains one of the strings in the set.

However, if I only put www or idjot on the EditText, no prompt will appear and it will then store the data to Firebase Database.

What I wanted is to validate all the possible text one by one and if the text was on the set of strings the alert dialog will appear and stop the user from posting a discussion.

I have a set of strings that contains a lot of profound words that can be a possible inputs by the users.

here are the string:

```
String[] items = { idiot, www.youtube.com, etc...};
```

here's my code for the validation:

```
discussion= discussion_description.getText().toString();


if (Arrays.asList(items).contains(discussion)){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddingDiscussionActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Please refrain yourself from posting profound words / URL")
            .setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting use-case. What isn't working about the code you shared though?

Comment: Hi Frank, Let's say I put a full link on the set of string example: "www.stackoverflow.com", What happen is if a user only types www. on the EditText, no restrictions will be made. I would like my validation to work as even if a user only types www. or anything thats related to a URL, a restriction will be implemented preventing the user to post that discussion.

Comment: In that case, have you tried to add `www.` to the `items` array?

Comment: Thank you Alex, I might as well do that then.